# Replace string with hostname

Tags: ansible

I've been searching up and down for a way to replace a string in a file with the contents of `ansible_hostname`. Say I have something similar to this in a configuration file:

```
kern.*       /syslog/SYSLOG_SERVER/kern.log 
auth.*       /syslog/SYSLOG_SERVER/auth.log
```

Is there an easy way in Ansible to replace all occurrences of `SYSLOG_SERVER` with the hostname of the server the configuration file is copied to? If anyone has an example or a link describing how to do this I would be super appreciative if you shared it.

Comment: Be careful with wording "*If anyone has an example or a link describing how to do this I would be super appreciative if you shared it.*" -- such questions are strictly off-topic on StackOverflow and get closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`replace` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/replace_module.html):

```
- replace:
    dest: /path/to/configuration/file
    regexp: SYSLOG_SERVER
    replace: '{{ ansible_hostname }}'
    backup: yes
```

`backup` parameter is optional, but since you will be experimenting at first, it is safer to leave it. You can leave it out once you have established the correct procedure.

Comment: Thanks techraf. I had to s/path/dest/ your example but other than your suggestion worked like a charm! Here's the final working play:     

 - name: Replace SYSLOG_SERVER with server name
      replace: 
        dest: /etc/rsyslog.conf
        regexp: SYSLOG_SERVER
        replace: '{{ansible_hostname}}'
        backup: yes

Comment: Ah, sorry, it was the new syntax, updated the answer. Since Ansible 2.3 (current `devel` version) `path` has become the preferred parameter name, and `dest`, `destfile`, `name` its aliases. [source](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/modules/files/replace.py#L150)

Comment: I just read about path replacing dest*. Thanks for the additional feedback! You rock!

Answer (score 0):

If the file is already out on the destination server you can use the lineinfile module to make sure the contents are what you want.

If the file is distributed/updated as part of a playbook run you can use the template module to dynamically inject the destionation node's hostname as it gets copied to the destionation.